# Login on Multiple Sub-Domains without Multisite

Tags: multisite, login, subdomains

I have a bit of an issue that is hard to find an answer on. My WordPress structure is like follows:

- Main Site: **domain.com**
- Sub-Site: **category1.domain.com**
- Sub-Site: **category2.domain.com**
- Etc.

All of these point to the same WordPress installation with the same database. The difference is that on **category1.domain.com** I query only the posts in the category1 category, same on **category2.domain.com** etc.

I am NOT running a Multisite setup because it seems to be something different from what I want. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Anyway, this setup works fine but logging in on the subdomains does not work properly. Users can login on **domain.com** and stay on the same page they logged in on, but trying to login on **category1.domain.com** automatically redirects them to **domain.com/wp-admin**.

The reason why I don't want to have a centralized login page on my main **domain.com**  is because I want a jQuery popup box with a login form on every page on my site, including the subdomains.

It seems that it might have to do with the *WordPress Address (URL)* and *Site Address (URL)* settings in wp-admin -> Settings -> General, but I'm unsure how I can set multiple subdomains in this setting.

Does anyone have any idea on how I might get this setup to work? Or am I better off taking a different approach (perhaps using Multisite after all?)

Comment: So you don't actually want separate admin areas, you just want a login form on every page? Can't you just have a login form on every page that redirects to the admin on the main domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically update the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in `wp-config.php` to reflect the requested host:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
```

As long as visitors don't click a link containing a different fully-qualified domain (or otherwise send a request to a different subdomain via a form action or some such), they should remain on the subdomain that was originally requested.

That said, I don't see any reason why the admin dashboard being served on `domain.com` alone would prevent you from adding a pop-up jQuery login form... If anything, I think it's kind of strange to serve the admin dashboard from those category-centric subdomains when it provides administrative functions for the entire site regardless of which (sub)domain it's accessed from. Intuition would lead me to think the administration dashboard for `category1.domain.com` would administer `category1` alone.

Comment: Seems like adding `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );` to my wp-config.php did the trick! I think the main issue was the jQuery login form trying to make a cross-domain login request (from **category.domain.com** to **domain.com**) and failing in the process. Anyway, thank you so much for the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You saved me from waking up whole night and try things LOL